# How to check the mouse is over something clickable?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm building a specialized viewer application which loads external SWFs.

```
var content:Sprite = ...
content.addChild(loader);
```

I listen to my top level content Sprite MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT events.
The over handler hides default cursor and displays a custom (zoom) cursor.
Out handler changes cursor back to default.

What I want to achieve is NOT showing the zoom cursor when the mouse is over a clickable item in the externally loaded SWF like a button or textlink.

The current code works perfectly for AVM1 swfs.
The problem lies with loaded swfs using AS3. 
For these the content MOUSE_OUT is fired and instantly MOUSE_OVER is fired as well, so the cursor remains wrong.

What this probably boils down to is: How to check the mouse is over a clickable child of content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some testing and the hint George gave me, this is the content `MOUSE_OVER` listener I just wrote (in Haxe) which seems to work:

```
public var mouseOverClickableContent:Bool;

private function onOverContentChild(event)
{   
    mouseOverClickableContent = false;
    if (event.target != content)
    {
        var obj:flash.display.InteractiveObject = cast event.target;

        while (obj != content)
        {
            if (   obj.hasEventListener(flash.events.MouseEvent.CLICK)
                || obj.hasEventListener(flash.events.MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP)
                || obj.hasEventListener(flash.events.MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN)
                || ( Std.is(obj, Sprite) && cast(obj, Sprite).buttonMode )
            ){
                mouseOverClickableContent = true;
                break;
            }
            obj = obj.parent;
        }
    }


}
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way of detecting if the mouse is over a TextField htmlText link, so I could add a TextField `htmlText.indexOf("<a") != -1` check there.

Unless someone knows a trick to detect mouse-over-textfield-links?

Answer (score 4):

Good question!

I've done a quick test. There is a method called [getObjectsUnderPoint()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint%28%29) which

> returns an array of objects that lie
>   under the specified point and are
>   children (or grandchildren, and so on)
>   of this DisplayObjectContainer
>   instance

according to the documentation.

Also

> any child objects that are
>   inaccessible for security reasons are
>   omitted from the returned array. To
>   determine whether this security
>   restriction affects the returned
>   array, call the
>   areInaccessibleObjectsUnderPoint()
>   method.

So I don't know how helpful this might be.

Here's my test nevertheless:

```
//make some clips interactive
for(var i:int = 0 ; i < numChildren ; i+=2){
    MovieClip(getChildAt(i)).mouseEnabled = true;
    MovieClip(getChildAt(i)).buttonMode = true;
    MovieClip(getChildAt(i)).mouseChildren = false;
}
//reuse this array
var clips:Array;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkClickables);
function checkClickables(event:Event):void {
    clips   = this.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(mouseX,mouseY));
    for(i = 0 ; i < clips.length ; i++){
        if(isInteractiveObject(clips[i])){
            trace(clips[i]);
        }
    }
}
function isInteractiveObject(object:*):Boolean{
    var extendsClass:XMLList = describeType(object).extendsClass;
    for each(var classDef:XML in extendsClass){
        if(classDef.@type == 'flash.display::InteractiveObject') return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have some clips on stage, and I'm making some of them 'clickable'.
Then onEnterFrame I'm checking if there are any instances of a subclass
of InteractiveObject( the superclass for anything clickable )

For some reason in my test, getObjectsUnderPoint() returned only Shape objects, no Sprites.
Maybe it might work in your configuration.

Also it seems a bit complicated.

Here's my second approach:

```
function getInteractiveObjects(container:DisplayObjectContainer):Array{
    var result:Array = [];
    for(var i:int = 0 ; i < container.numChildren ; i++){
        if(container.getChildAt(i) is Sprite || container.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip) result.push(container.getChildAt(i));
        if(container.getChildAt(i) is DisplayObjectContainer){
            var clips:Array = getInteractiveObjects(DisplayObjectContainer(container.getChildAt(i)));
            var clipsNum:int = clips.length;
            for(var j:int = 0 ; j < clipsNum ; j++)
                if(clips[j] is Sprite || clips[j] is MovieClip) result.push(clips[j])
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Use a recursive function that gets potentially interactive objective inside a clips(like the loader content). If it is either a Sprite or MovieClip, it's 'clickable'.

```
var iclips:Array = getInteractiveObjects(this);
for(i  = 0 ; i < iclips.length ; i++){
    trace(iclips[i].name);
    //do extra tests here
    if(iclips[i].hasEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER)) trace(iclips[i].name + ' has roll over');
    //etc.
}
```

You can then do extra tests, depending on what exactly you're looking for ( either it has and event listener for mouse events, either it is mouseEnabled, has buttonMode set to true, etc. )

This way you don't need to check for any mouse over ( don't have to wait for user interaction or call a function all the time ) and once you got the clips that don't behave the way you want to, you can change their behavior (mouseChildren = false, or something).

HTH